# FreeCAD import error while using Spyder "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing FreeCAD: The specified procedure could not be found."

Tags: python, importerror, freecad

My FreeCAD software runs on Windows 10. Its built-in Python console uses Python 3.8. In order to import its modules to an external Python， I created a Python3.8 environment in anaconda and the module can be successfully imported with Jupyter QtConsole. However, import errors show up when I do the same thing in Spyder. Does anyone have a similar problem? Any idea what is going on here? （see the images below）
[successful import in Jupyter QtConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9c9A.png)
[Failed import in Spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66qiF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall the Freecad program and use ananconda to reinstall the Freecad package. Now the Spyder works fine.

FYI: Use the following command (I copied from the wiki page) to do the installation: "conda create --name fcenv --channel conda-forge freecad"

Creating a new environment seems to be necessary. Otherwise, the installation will fail.